# How do I pass in distribution functions as parameters for a function?

Tags: c++

I would like to pass in random distribution functions (they can be different depending on what I want, which can change), so I'd like them to be a parameter function essentially, how can I achieve this?

```
auto GenerateRandomVector(double &mean, double &SD, int &VecSize) -> std::vector<double> {
        std::random_device rnd_device;
        std::mt19937 mersenne_engine {rnd_device()};  
        std::normal_distribution<double> dist {mean, SD}; //Hw do I make this an argument? 

         auto gen = [&dist, &mersenne_engine]() {
                   return dist(mersenne_engine);
               };

        std::vector<int> vec(VecSize);
        std::generate(vec.begin(), vec.end(), gen);

        return vec;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply take it by reference (if you want to keep its internal state) or pass it by value.

Example using references:

```
std::mt19937& prng() {
    thread_local std::mt19937 mersenne_engine(std::random_device{}());
    return mersenne_engine;
}

std::vector<double> GenerateRandomVector(double& mean, double& SD,
                                         std::size_t VecSize,
                                         std::normal_distribution<double>& dist)
{
    auto gen = [&dist](){ return dist(prng()); };

    std::vector<double> vec(VecSize);       // Note: `double`, not `int`
    std::generate(vec.begin(), vec.end(), gen);
    mean = std::accumulate(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 0.) / vec.size();

    return vec;
}
```

Note: Don't initialize a new PRNG every time you call `GenerateRandomVector`. Initialize one PRNG and use it everywhere as I showed above.

If you need to support other types of distributions, you could make it a function template:

```
template<class Dist>
auto GenerateRandomVector(double& mean, double& SD,
                          std::size_t VecSize, Dist& dist)
{
    using result_type = typename Dist::result_type;

    auto gen = [&dist](){ return dist(prng()); };

    std::vector<result_type> vec(VecSize);  //  type depends on Dist
    std::generate(vec.begin(), vec.end(), gen);
    mean = std::accumulate(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 0.) / vec.size();

    return vec;
}
```

If you use C++11, you need to add a trailing return type:

```
template<class Dist>
auto GenerateRandomVector(double &mean, double &SD, std::size_t VecSize,
                          Dist& dist) -> std::vector<typename Dist::result_type>
{
```

Comment: What if i want to use a distribution instead? Like a uniform distribution and all the other ones instead? How would I be able to pass those in? Can I simple just template it?

Comment: @Steveit Yes, I added that as an example

Comment: this is awesome, I'll definitely give it another go!

Comment: Yep it works just fine thank you very much!

Comment: just a question how do I accept the answer

Comment: @Steveit I see that you found that out. :-)